# Bash, wihle read line by line, split strings on line divided by ",", store to array

Tags: arrays, bash, variables, while-loop

I need to read file line by line, and every line split by ",", and store to array.

File source_file.

```
usl-coop,/root
usl-dev,/bin
```

Script.

```
i=1
while read -r line; do
IFS="," read -ra para_$i <<< $line
echo ${para_$i[@]}
((i++))
done < source_file
```

Expected output.

```
para_1[0]=usl-coop
para_1[1]=/root
para_2[0]=usl-dev
para_2[1]=/bin
```

Script will out error about echo.

```
./sofimon.sh: line 21: ${para_$i[@]}: bad substitution
```

When I echo array one by one field, for example

```
echo para_1[0]
```

it shows, that variables are stored.

But I need use it with variable within, something like this.

```
${para_$i[1]}
```

Is possible to do this?

Thanks.

S.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is a trick to simulate 2D arrays using [associative arrays](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#Arrays). It works nice and I think is the most flexible and extensible:

```
declare -A para
i=1
while IFS=, read -r -a line; do
    for j in ${!line[@]}; do
       para[$i,$j]="${line[$j]}"
    done
   ((i++)) ||:
done < source_file
declare -p para
```

will output:

```
declare -A para=([1,0]="usl-coop" [1,1]="/root" [2,1]="/bin" [2,0]="usl-dev" )
```

Without modifying your script that much you could use [indirect variable expansion](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#Shell-Parameter-Expansion). It's sometimes used in simpler scripts:

```
i=1
while IFS="," read -r -a para_$i; do
        n="para_$i[@]"
        echo "${!n}"
        ((i++)) ||:
done < source_file
declare -p ${!para_*}
```

or basically the same with a *nameref* [a named reference to another variable](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#Shell-Parameters) (side note: see how `[@]` needs to be part of the variable in indirect expansion, but not in named reference):

```
i=1
while IFS="," read -r -a para_$i; do
        declare -n n
        n="para_$i"
        echo "${n[@]}"
        ((i++)) ||:
done < source_file
declare -p ${!para_*}
```

both scripts above will output the same:

```
usl-coop /root
usl-dev /bin
declare -a para_1=([0]="usl-coop" [1]="/root")
declare -a para_2=([0]="usl-dev" [1]="/bin")
```

That said, I think you shouldn't read your file into memory at all. It's just a bad design. Shell and bash is build around passing your files with pipes, streams, fifos, redirections, process substitutions, etc. without ever saving/copying/storing the file. If you have a file to parse, you should stream it to another process, parse and save the result, without ever storing the whole input in memory. If you want some data to find inside a file, use `grep` or `awk`.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a short `awk` script that do the task.

```
awk 'BEGIN{FS=",";of="para_%d[%d]=%s\n"}{printf(of, NR, 0, $1);printf(of, NR, 1, $2)}' input.txt
```

Provide the desired output.

Explanation:

```
BEGIN{
  FS=",";                # set field seperator to `,`
  of="para_%d[%d]=%s\n"  # define common printf output format
}
{                         # for each input line
  printf(of, NR, 0, $1);  # output for current line, [0], left field
  printf(of, NR, 1, $2)   # output for current line, [1], right field
}
```